# For loop cannot store output of looped function

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a function to simulate genetic drift and I would like to loop it over multiple values of each parameter
The function is below:

```
wright.fisher<-function(p,Ne,nsim,t){
  N <-Ne/2
  NA1 <- 2*N*p 
  NA2 <- 2*N*(1-p)
  k <- matrix(0, nrow = max(2, t), ncol = nsim)
  k[1,] <- rep(NA1, nsim)
  for (j in 1:nsim) {
    for (i in 2:t) {
      k[i, j] <- rbinom(1, 2*N, prob = k[i-1, j] / (2*N))
    }
  }
  k <- as.matrix(k/(2*N))
  t(k)
}
```

I've attempted to loop it over t (generations of drift), but that fails, the following is my code:

```
locifreq<-runif(49, .4, 0.8)
gen <- 2:99
looppop<-list()
for (i in 2:length(gen)){
  looppop[i]<-lapply(locifreq,wright.fisher,3000,4,gen[i])
}
```

Doing that results in an error for each iteration -

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In pop[i] <- lapply(locifreq, wright.fisher, 3000, 4,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In pop[i] <- lapply(locifreq, wright.fisher, 3000, 4,  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I suspect that the issue may be in storing the output into a matrix, and perhaps the function isn't accessing the matrix correctly, but i'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to help without any sample data and a reproducible example. I noticed that you declare `looppop` but then populate `pop` inside the `for` loop. Can you please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example that reproduces the warning.

Comment: I reproduced this example and it worked for me on R v3.4.3, generating a 98 element list of lists, where the size of each element grows in each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add list() inside any for loop that populates a new list inside the loop:

```
locifreq<-runif(49, .4, 0.8)
gen <- 2:99
looppop<-list()
for (i in 2:length(gen)){
  looppop[i]<-list(lapply(locifreq,wright.fisher,3000,4,gen[i])) # note the list( addition
}
```

[image]

Comment: The real answer is the difference between simplifying and preserving.  `[` will simplify and `[[` will preserve.  My answer below produces the exact same result as this answer, which can be tested using `set.seed` and `identical`.  The reason the poster's code didn't work was because he asked for simplification with `[` instead of preserve with `[[`.

Comment: If an alternative soluton produces “the exact same result” then it is not “the real answer” it is an alternative answer.

Comment: By real answer I mean that the problem was caused by simplification vs preservation.  Understanding the difference between preservation and simplification in lists is what allows a person to understand why the original code did not produce the right answer.  The "real" answer would be to explain simplification and preservation in lists.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I am not completely sure what you want but does this give you what you want?  I used [[i]] on the looppop instead of [i]

```
locifreq<-runif(49, .4, 0.8)
gen <- 2:99
looppop<-list()
for (i in 2:length(gen)){
  looppop[[i]]<-lapply(locifreq,wright.fisher,3000,4,gen[i])
```

When lists are concatenated, one of two things will happen: preservation or simplifications.  Your code uses `[` so simplification is attempted.  Because your matrices at each iteration are different dimensions, simplification produces and error.  But if you use `[[` then the concatenation will use preservation and the result will be a list of your matrices of ever increasing size.  The accepted answer changes the catenation from that of matrices to that of lists. In that case the `[` is preserving a list, not a matrix and the code runs as needed.